# Random Forest does not classify

Tags: python, classification, random-forest

I got the feature vectors by using transfer learning on the dataset (images)

```
X =
[[0.06381412 1.5189143  0.7007909  ... 0.22550535 0.56980544 0.07307615]
 [0.06381412 1.5189143  0.7007909  ... 0.22550535 0.56980544 0.07307615]
 [0.06381412 1.5189143  0.7007909  ... 0.22550535 0.56980544 0.07307615]
 ...
 [0.06381412 1.5189143  0.7007909  ... 0.22550535 0.56980544 0.07307615]
 [0.06381412 1.5189143  0.7007909  ... 0.22550535 0.56980544 0.07307615]
 [0.06381412 1.5189143  0.7007909  ... 0.22550535 0.56980544 0.07307615]]







imgs_train, imgs_test, y_train, y_test, = train_test_split(X, Y,test_size=0.33, random_state=42)                
Mrfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000, 
                                 bootstrap = True,
                                 oob_score = True,
                                 criterion = 'gini', 
                                 max_features = 'auto',
                                 max_depth = dep,
                                 min_samples_split = int(3000), 
                                 min_samples_leaf = int(1000), 
                                 max_leaf_nodes = None,
                                 n_jobs=-1
                                )       
Mrfc.fit(imgs_train,y_train)
y_predict = Mrfc.predict(imgs_train)
```

The output of y_predict is all zeros:

> [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. ...]

Y contains the labels (either 0 or 1)
The model is unable to make predictions. What can I do?

Comment: X is (1050, 2048)... 1050 images... 2048 features per image

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the case that you have skewed classes in your labels so a prediction of all zeros actually gives you a high accuracy? In this case you might want to try setting class_weight="balanced" for your RandomForestClassifier.